# Finding common values in a 2 column SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following database named 'social_links' where Column A knows Column B:

```
A B
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 5
4 2
5 3
5 4
```

How do I query in python to find for example: User 1 knows User 2 and at the same time knows User 3. User 2 in the other hand, knows User 3 meaning all 3 users (User 1, 2, 3) knows each other and display the result in a dataframe as below?

```
    A B C
1   1 2 3
2   1 2 4
3   2 3 5
4   2 4 5
```

Thank you.

I have drafted the following codes:

```
3users_query = '''???
               '''

c.execute(3users_query)

dfUsersKnown = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
dfUsersKnown
```

Comment: I don't understand your results,  1 should be `2 3 4`, 2 should be `1 3 5`, 3 should be `1 2 5`, 4 should be `1 2 5` and 5 should be `3 4 5`.  You would need a 5x5 array for this.  Each line sets two cells ("1 2" and "2 1").  It isn't hard to compute, but pandas isn't going to help much.

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that will get your desired results.

```
with users(U) as (
  select distinct A from social_links
  union
  select distinct B from social_links
)
select * from users u1
  JOIN users u2 
  JOIN users u3
  WHERE u1.U < u2.U AND EXISTS (SELECT * from social_links l WHERE (u1.U=l.A and u2.U=l.B) OR (u2.U=l.A and u1.U=l.B))
  AND u1.U < u3.U AND EXISTS (SELECT * from social_links l WHERE (u1.U=l.A and u3.U=l.B) OR (u3.U=l.A and u1.U=l.B))
  AND u2.U < u3.U AND EXISTS (SELECT * from social_links l WHERE (u2.U=l.A and u3.U=l.B) OR (u3.U=l.A and u2.U=l.B));
```

If you already have a `users` table you can substitute it in the query and avoid all the `WITH` part.

[Here is a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TS089KG6).

Comment: Thank you! The fiddle link is a good step for me to play around and understand SQL better.